# Javascript - How is this clock function updating time if there is no setInterval function?

Tags: javascript, time, settimeout, setinterval

I thought that startTime is only called once and so is setTimeout. Why doesn't this need setInterval instead?

```
function startTime() {
  var today = new Date();
  var h = today.getHours();
  var m = today.getMinutes();
  var s = today.getSeconds();
  m = checkTime(m);
  s = checkTime(s);
  document.getElementById('time').innerHTML =
  h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
  var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
}
function checkTime(i) {
  if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
  return i;
}

starTime()
```

Comment: It calls itself `var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);` recursively

Comment: Because it is within itself, you would not want it to keep running forever^forever

Answer (score 4):

The function calls itself at the end:

> var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);

Whenever the function is called another timeout is set. It effectively acts as a setInterval but doing it this way would also allow you to only set the timeout under certain conditions.

Comment: This is true, but the variable is defined and never called?

Comment: @dstana The `setTimeout` function is still called. The variable is just holding the return value of `setTimeout` (which is a timeout ID), which could be passed in 
 a call to `clearTimeout` later on. However, the variable assignment is unneeded here since it is not used.

Comment: I see, calling the function within itself creates an infinite loop here. So the timeout of 500 is really just how fast it will run. 500 timeout = twice per second